# Sticky element isn't fully viewable on mobile when scrolling down

Tags: javascript, html, css, salesforce-commerce-cloud

I have a navigation element in the middle of a page that needs to be sticky when scrolling past it

[image: product navigation]

On mobile, when scrolling down the page, the navigation is hidden at the top of the screen.

[image: product navigation hidden]

When scrolling up, it comes back into full view at the top of the page.

HTML:

```
<div class="sticky-top" >
<nav id="pdp-product-nav" class="init-sticky-nav" >
...nav elements...
</nav></div>
```

CSS:

```
.sticky-top {
   position: sticky;
   top: 0;
   z-index: 1020;
}
.pdp-product-nav {
   background: #e0eff9;
   display: flex;
   overflow-x: scroll;
   height: 48px;
   margin-bottom: 39px;
   flex-wrap: nowrap;
   overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

JS:

```
initStickyNav: function () {
    var $navElement = $('#pdp-product-nav');
    if($navElement.hasClass('init-sticky-nav')) {
        $navElement.closest('.experience-dynamic-productNav').addClass('sticky-top');
    }
}
```

JS essentially just checks if a boolean attribute is enabled, which will add init-sticky-nav if it is, and then just adds the sticky-top class. This is just there since the ability to enable/disable sticky nav is wanted.

The question is, how do I prevent it from hiding when scrolling down? I can add `padding-top` to the `.sticky-top` class and that fixes it when scrolling down, but then there is a large gap when scrolling up.

Comment: Do you want it to stay at the middle of the screen? If so use position: fixed;

Comment: @Grumpy It should stay at the top of the page, as sticky, when scrolling up/down. Which it does, but it's going behind the top of the page when scrolling down instead of visible